# Android: Issues in animating edittext?

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

I tried to animate the edittext when user starts editing it.
I have tried the following code,

`````````
 EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
 Animation  anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.anim);
 anim.setInterpolator((new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()));
 anim.setFillAfter(true);
txtPassword.startAnimation(anim);

anim.xml
````````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-50%p" android:duration="100"/>
</set>
`````````

The animation works fine.
but the edittext stopped userinteraction after animation.
If the user touches the previous position of the edittext of the screen, the keyboard appears.
but the edittext actually in the new position should respond. What I have to do?

[image]

[image]
I hope that someone can edit my question in correct english format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(USEFUL HINT: There is a Android library for using the Honeycomb (Android 3.0) animation API on all versions of the platform back to 1.0!. It is called [NineOldAndroid](http://nineoldandroids.com/).)

(USEFUL HINT (Android Developers, [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)): Starting with Android 3.0, the preferred way of animating views is to use the android.animation package APIs. These Animator-based classes change actual properties of the View object, such as alpha and translationX. This behavior is contrasted to that of the pre-3.0 Animation-based classes, which instead animate only how the view is drawn on the display. In particular, the ViewPropertyAnimator class makes animating these View properties particularly easy and efficient. )

(NOTE THAT: BELOW SOLUTION IS FOR PRE-HONEYCOMB.)

Animations with android is a bit tricky to understand, in contrast to iOS. You need to know that;

- only the ghost of the Android View subclass is animated.
- and the grave is still at the ancestor coordinate

So the solution might be;

- Block touch events to view

  `animatingView.setEnabled(FALSE);`
- animate view
- Remove animatingView

  `animatingView.setVisibility(GONE); 
  (animatingView.getParent()).removeView(animatingView);`
- Add the exact duplicate of view to the new coordinates.

Comment: Thank for your reply but what about gingerbird(android 2.3)? need soln.

Comment: below part is the solution i provided. Which part you don't understand?

Comment: you said its works android 3.0 but needed for below android 3.0 version

Comment: no, i said my solution works for PRE-HONEYCOMB, which means versions released previously than honeycomb.

Comment: Also, there is a perfect animation wrapper called NineOldAndroid ( http://nineoldandroids.com/ ) written by Jake Wharton. It would be easier to implement than my solution. Good Luck!